# Best way to determine how the answers from a survey correspond to each other?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, stepwise-regression

I conducted a survey on about 200 people and would like to know if there are any patterns in how people responded. To be more specific, is there a correlation between how people responded to different questions? And would we be able to predict how someone would respond to a question based on their other responses? I'm wondering what the best method would be to go about this. I'm using R to find results. What has come to mind is a correlation matrix or even multiple linear stepwise regression models. One of my issues has been that there are about 40 variables so that would be a very large and messy correlation matrix and a ton of regression models.